# Hide vendor informations for visitors on dokan plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

Hello i'm using Dokan lite plugin and martfury theme (marketplace), i want to hide vendors informations to the visitors
so the user can see the vendor's informations only after login or register, is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a plugin for that named Dokan Vendor Info Hider.

1. Navigate to Plugins -> Add New
2. Search Dokan Vendor Info Hider
3. Click install and activate respectively.

Now go to-  Dokan -> Settings

On the General Tab, you will find “Hide Vendor Info“. Now choose the info you want to hide.

Comment: thank you, i tried to do this but in this case  no one can see the vendor informations, and  what i want is different: the informations appear only if the user log in or register